# Using delimited rowkey in hbase

Tags: hbase

Can i have  a combination of 3 Strings as the row key in HBase? For instance, a combination of X , Y and Z values identify one unique record.

I will be connecting to Hbase using Java

Could you please let me know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the risk of being trivial, concatenate your strings with a separator, to produce something like "x|y|z" for instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use delimiter such as '|' or length prefixed strings for rowkeys.

you could also refer to OpenTSDB for [schema design](http://opentsdb.net/schema.html).

Answer (score 0):

HBase doesn't stop you from doing that. Although you could use any character as a separator, try using something uncommon, say **"~"** or **"^"**. Reason being, characters like **"|"** or **","** are highly likely to appear as a part of the data.

A couple of suggestions though :

- Try to keep the length of rowkey as less as possible.
- Try to use numeric keys instead of strings if possible.

HTH

P.S. : The best way to get answers to these type of queries is to try it. This is something which should not take more than a few minutes.

---

You can make use of PrefixFilter to achieve that. Given a prefix, specified when you instantiate the filter instance, all rows that match this prefix are returned to the client. The constructor is:

**public PrefixFilter(byte[] prefix)**

Example :

**Filter filter = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("9874541235^MOBILEDEVICE^MOBILESOURCE"));**

This will give you all the rows which are starting with **9874541235^MOBILEDEVICE^MOBILESOURCE**.

Comment: According to my requirement I am actually supposed to use the key as a phone number(10 digits) , a code which would be atleast 8 characters and another code of 8 code characters. So my key would be something like, 9874541235^MOBILEDEVICE^MOBILESOURCE. I unfortunately have to use this combination as keys since only these together form a unique key. Please  suggest me

Comment: Hi I have a problem using 9874541235^MOBILEDEVICE^MOBILESOURCE as a key. This is not a unique value. A combination of 9874541235^MOBILEDEVICE^MOBILESOURCE^VALUE is a unique key. But the problem is, when i am trying to retrieve the information i will only have 9874541235^MOBILEDEVICE^MOBILESOURCE as the request. Do u have any suggestions how to design the same?

Comment: @Tariq HI Tariq - would love to get some feedback from you on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334669/hbase-row-key-for-time-series-data
Thanks